# Can't load Custom Widget in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've tried both a simple inline tutorial and using the cookiecutter template to make Jupyter Widgets but the widgets don't load.

When I try this [tutorial](http://kazuar.github.io/jupyter-widget-tutorial/) even for the hello world widget, I just get "A Jupyter Widget" printed out and in the console I get "404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js".

When I try an inline example, I get this error in the console "404 GET /static/@jupyter-widgets/base.js" The code for the inline examples is just

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode, validate


class HelloWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('HelloView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('hello').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)

%%javascript
require.undef('hello');

define('hello', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {

    var HelloView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

    // Render the view.
    render: function() {
        this.el.textContent = 'Hello World!';
    },
    });

    return {
        HelloView: HelloView
    };
});
```

This is in a conda virtual environment, Jupyter 4.2.1 and Notebook 4.3.1

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue when I forgot to run `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` after installing through `pip`; see here for details http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html. Seems like `conda` should have enabled the extension for you. I don't have any experience with `conda` but seems like you could have installed `ipywidgets` either via `conda install -c anaconda ipywidgets` or `conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets`, think maybe the `conda-forge` install could be more up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall all jupyter and ipython related pip packages solved this problem for me.